# Do I really need CORS here with Swagger?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, .net-6.0

I developed an API to give public access to some company data, which is of no value to hackers. It's public data that can be sourced from other websites.

I developed the project using default Visual Studio ASP.Net Core API templates. One thing I noticed it's using **CORS** and I don't know how it got in here to be honest.

However, the default Policy is set as any domain, any method and any header:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(p =>
    p.AddPolicy("corsapp", builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
        }));
```

Do I even need CORS, if I am only allowing the API to run from a single origin, which already has HTTPS?

What benefit, when the API works as is?

**Program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

//do I really need this!?!
builder.Services.AddCors(p => p.AddPolicy("corsapp", builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
}));

var startup = new Startup(builder.Configuration);
startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services);

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

startup.Configure(app);

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

//why!?!
app.UseCors("corsapp");

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

**UPDATE**

I've re-worded my OP based on Rahul's excellent video about CORS from Chen's answer below. However, I am still confused if I should configure CORS here to give a specific **single** origin as I am more worried someone after me may not configure this Policy correctly if the API is required in more than two places.

Thanks

Comment: You would need to have CORS enabled on the server side, to serve API responses to client applications (an SPA typcically) that have been loaded from another domain. You need to decide whether this fits your scenario.

Comment: Think your API is used by others. But you want the specific (domain, port) to access it. Then CORS is used.

Comment: Do you know that is CORS? If no, I advice to inquire about that. Trust me... it won't be wasted time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to know if your program provides API responses to client applications loaded from other domains to determine if you need to enable CORS.

For example, there are two cases where no action is needed for CORS support:

1. Swagger UI is hosted on the same server as the application itself (same host and port).
2. The application is located behind a proxy that enables the required CORS headers. This may already be covered within your organization.

You can get a better understanding and use of CORS through [this link](https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/asp_net_core_cors_demystified/) and [this official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: The 1st link and embedded video was perfect! Well documented and explained by Rahul. And again my OP stand because since I am publishing my API to the public domain from a single origin, then I don't need CORs because CORS is not a "security" feature. It's a door controlling system to determine what redirects are allowed or not. The video was an eye opener. Thanks!

Comment: I've re-worded my OP. Please read and comment. Thanks